# Developing a custom NewForm

Tags: development, list, sharepoint-foundation, feature-receiver, layouts

I have created a custom layout in `_layours/PhoneBook/createform.aspx` and then wrote the following code to run upon activation:

```
    private void newAddFormForMembers(SPWeb web)
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["MemberRecords"];
        SPContentType ct = list.ContentTypes["item"];
        ct.NewFormUrl = "_layouts/createform.aspx";

        ct.Update();
    }
```

So this works, it compiles and life is grand, no errors, when I go to the list page, click on MemeberRecords and click Add I get:

```
The file '/_layouts/~masterurl/default.master' does not exist.
```

My list is created programtically on activation of the web part, so this [tutorial](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2011/05/12/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-how-to-create-a-customized-list-edit-form-for-development-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) helped some but not a lot. especially when they tied it all to list deffinitions.

So **How do I fix this error?**

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with the path to the masterpage in `createform.aspx` file.

Look for the `DynamicMasterPageFile` in your code and make sure the path is set as in this example:

```
DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"
```